# Android api level 23, how to read files on emulator?

Tags: android

I am trying to list all the files in Downloads folder of an emulator which has an SDCard.
Now when I do this

```
 File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

the value of `file` is "/storage/18E2-1B1D/Download"

if I do `file.listFiles()` it returns `null`.

I do not understand what this means, 18E2-1B1D?
Do I have to write seperate code for emulator and devices?
I have set all possible permissions but it isn't working.
Also I have checked all the stackoverflow threads.

Answer (score 1):

The [File.listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Most likely `file` denotes a directory. Maybe it just doesn't exist yet or a permission is denied, causing an I/O error.

`18E2-1B1D` is just an identifier for the SD card, so you shouldn't have to worry about this. In the end emulator and devices should work the same if you're only using high level APIs.

---

But in Android api level 23 the permission model changed. Now you need to [request permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) at runtime. The call

```
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

should return `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. If not, you'll need to call

```
requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, id);
```

and handle the result asynchronously in [onRequestPermissionsResult (int, String[], int[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult%28int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29).

The permission still needs to be defined in the manifest.
If you want to use the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead, just adapt it in the code as well.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().isDirectory() is true, so it is an actual directory? What do you mean by "it doesn;t exist yet"?

Comment: What does `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().exists()` return?

Comment: Thanks tynn,  but the problem was the API level. It seems api level 23 is not stable yet. I moved down to api 19 and the same code worked as expected.

Comment: @VishwanathPratapSingh you're almost right. I totally forgot, that a permission is needed for reading the external directory. The api level 23 is stable of course, just different. I've updated the answer.